# Biomedical Engineering -- Signal Processing in R [Book Recommendations]

Tags: r, references

Would anyone be able to recommend a good book for biomedical engineering in R? In particular, something that is more specific to signal processing such as accelerometer or EMG signals?

Comment: https://rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Comment: Thank you, Tony. Is there any particular cheatsheet you had in mind? I've browsed through those and I'm not sure which would be directed at signal processing in biomedical research.